# TF2 Tutorial Static Broadcaster Python

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, tf2, tutorials, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20static%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29

Hi, running through this tutorial and its not clear whether I should be creating my broadcaster source code file in `learning_tf2/src/nodes` or `learning_tf2/nodes`.

In section 2.1 it says just make a directory called `nodes`, whereas in 3 that `nodes` directory now lives under `src`.

Would be good to fix inconsistency. Also, does it matter where this file is located within the package? I've seen other places where Python files are in a dir called `scripts` as opposed to `src`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349117/tf2-tutorial-static-broadcaster-python/) by [shdblowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/51674/shdblowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the `nodes` directory should be directly under the package rather than `src` folder. According to [REP8-Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0008.html#installing-scripts-with-catkin),

> "The recommended layout is to put all
> of your package's importable Python
> code in the src folder of your package
> and in a "Python package" with the
> same name as your package. In this
> case a "Python package" is a folder
> which contains a `__init__.py` file,
> indicating that the folder contains
> additional Python packages and
> modules."

The `src` folder thus should store Python packages and modules if you want to make them importable into other ROS packages.

> Also, does it matter where this file
> is located within the package? I've
> seen other places where Python files
> are in a dir called scripts as opposed
> to src.

As far as I know, technically, it does not matter where the file is located within the package since `rosrun` is able to find the location of the executable for a package recursively ([rosrun-source code](https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/2b307e1854ebf3954a5b4110f891278f555e79a6/tools/rosbash/scripts/rosrun#L73)). So as long as your executable file- python script is in the directory of your ROS package (under `src` in the catkin workspace, since `catkin_make` command only looks for packages under `src` dir) and your local workspace is properly sourced, `rosrun` should be able to find that executable.

However, conventionally, according to an excerpt from [REP8-Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0008.html#installing-scripts-with-catkin),

> "We distinguish between "nodes" and
> "scripts" for clarity to users. Nodes
> are executable Python files that
> conform to the ROS node API. Scripts
> are executable Python files that do
> not conform to the ROS node API."

Aslo from [Installing Python scripts and modules](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html)

> “Standard ROS practice is to place all
> executable Python programs in a
> package subdirectory named nodes/ or
> scripts/. Their usage is the same, the
> two names distinguish ROS nodes from
> other executable Python scripts.”

So I think, conventionally, an executable python script that contains ROS nodes should go to `nodes` folder.

I guess distinctions are the convention and good practices to make your package structure more clear.

I think the rationale for ROS users putting python scripts into `scripts` folder is based on the common practice for python packages. In Python, people usually put top-level executable scripts in the scripts/ (or bin/) directory and place python packages and modules (used by scripts) into the src/ directory. As for the distinction between nodes and scripts in ROS, I don't really know if it's a horrible practice to not separate nodes and scripts. Tbh, personally, I've seldom seen `nodes` folder. My guess is perhaps ROS users generally consider nodes/ as a subset of scripts/, since scripts are any executable python scripts for any purpose.

---

Originally posted by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) with karma: 241 on 2020-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shdblowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/51674/shdblowers/) on 2020-04-12**:
hi, thanks for the detailed answer. very informative.

**Comment by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) on 2020-04-13**:
No problem!